# How to use openssl_x509_parse and openssl_x509_verify on PHP

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, certificate, lumen

I wanted to verify my certificate:

In this PHP doc, we can see that `openssl_x509_verify` function must return 1: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-x509-verify.php

When I did this:

```
$certificate = base64_decode($payload['sca']); // I have certificate begin with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
$chaincert = openssl_x509_read($certificate); // I have OpenSSL X.509 resource
```

Dump of `$chaincert`:
[image]

Now I try to use the `openssl_x509_verify` function with parameters:

1. $certificate
2. $publicKey

To get the public key, I do this:

```
$chainPublicKey = openssl_get_publickey($chaincert);
```

Then, I try:

```
$verify = openssl_x509_verify($chaincert, $chainPublicKey);
```

And, the result of $verify = **0**, not **1**.

As the PHP documentation says ( https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-x509-verify.php ), I must have a result equal to 1.

Could you please help me?

EDIT:

I was able to solve my problem.
My publicKey and my privateKey were not matching.

Comment: "Returns 1 if the signature is correct, 0 if it is incorrect, and -1 on error." So check your PHP logs for an error.

Comment: Thank's for your response. I have 0 now but nothing in log (it's not a 500 to return 0 for openssl_x509_verify).

I edit my message

Comment: Are you sure $certificate is signed by $chaincert's private key? Error 0 means it is not.

It is difficult to determine without the actual $certificate and $certchain x509 certificate. You may add them to the question. There is no security issue in providing certificates here.

Comment: @SujayKumar Thank's for your response. Indeed you are right, since I managed to solve my problem. It came from the fact that the publicKey and the privateKey were not in agreement.